# Accessing this element in scope (and data attribute) where attributes match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following snippet:

```js
$(".tab").on("click", function() {
  var tabID = $(this).attr("data-item");
  $('.image[data-item = ' + tabID + ']').addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<div class="tabbedContent">

  <div class="imageWrapper">
     <div class="image" data-item="item--1">
      <!-- image -->
     </div>
     <div class="image" data-item="item--2">
      <!-- image -->
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs__rapper">
    <div class="tab" data-item="item--1" >
      <!-- tab text here -->
    </div>
    <div class="tab" data-item="item--2" >
      <!-- tab text here -->
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Basically, when a user clicks a tab, it displays an image assigned to that section (they're linked through `data-item`).

However, with the following:

`$('.image[data-item = ' + tabID + ']').addClass('active');`

If I have two of these tabbed modules on one page (if I have two on the same page, the `data-items` will be the same as they both start from 1), then images in both sections change.

What I'm trying to do is change the tab that's in scope by using `this`.

However, I'm unsure on how to do this, I've tried (need something like this):

```
$(this + '[data-item = '+tabID+']').addClass('active');
```

Am I far off?

Comment: Can you also share the HTML for one `.tab` to better understand the relation between `.image` & `.tab`

Comment: @palaѕн - Have updated in question :)

Answer (score 0):

Since`.tab` is scoped inside `.tabbedContent`:

```
$(this).parent('.tabs__rapper').parent('.tabbedContent').find('.image[data-item='+tabID+']').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Sorry, `.image` is not in `.tab` (I've updated my question showing the markup)

Comment: Ok updated solution. But I recommend instead using unique id's if you can as it would make your code more flexible in future.

Answer (score 0):

try to stop the event propagation when declaring it :

```js
$(".tab").on("click", function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var tabID = $(this).attr("data-item");
  $('.image[data-item = ' + tabID + ']').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, `.image` is inside `.tab`, you can change the tab that's in scope by using:

```
$(".tab").on("click", function() {
  var tabID = $(this).attr("data-item");
  $(this).closest('.tabbedContent').find('.image[data-item='+tabID+']').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Sorry, `.image` is not in `.tab` (I've updated my question showing the markup)

Comment: @Freddy You can try the updated code. Hope it helps!